# Connection to SQL Server from classic ASP

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic, odbc

This is a fairly noob question. I'm trying to set up a dev environment on my own machine by setting up a copy of a prod environment. To do so, I'm setting up a connection to a SQL Server database from classic ASP. I am a bit new both ASP and SQL Server, so I'm having some difficulties.

I imported a backup of the database already, and got that setup.  Here is the db_connection file I have:

```
<% 
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "myDatabase", "myLogin", "myPassword"

%>
```

This all works fine on the prod server, but on my machine I get:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

What driver would I need to download and where would I need to put it?  Or is that really the issue here?

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306345)

Comment: @EmmanuelN Thanks, that had some useful info.  The problem was even simpler than all that, though, I just needed to use a connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like its looking for a 'Data Source Name' file, but there's another way.

try opening the DB connection using a 'connection string'
it should look something like:

```
conn.open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False; 
uid= myLogin; pwd=myPassword;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Data Source=myServer"
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was looking through several places that use connection strings, but there were so many options I didn't know which ones to use.  I should ask this in another question, but do you know off the top of your head if user passwords are persisted in a backup restored in another location?

Comment: well, yes and no. the login's at the Database level go with it and get restored, but the ones at the server level don't. you can make it work  but it will require you to create server login's at the new server, and map them to the ones you have using `sp_change_users_login 'Auto_fix', <login name>`